# Why we say OpenCL is Standard

Tags: opencl

in the definition of OpenCl always I see **"OpenCl is standard"**. my question what is exactly standard language and why OpenCl is Standard?
thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you try to Google this first?

**OpenCL** is an open standard governed by the **Khronos** organization.

See: https://www.khronos.org/opencl/

Comment: thank you for your answer but what is mean open standard

Comment: I get downvoted for trying to help you? Harsh. Khronos is open governance; anyone can join and help create the standards. Read all about it on their site I linked to.